# Access Textblock in Controltemplate in App.xaml, in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I Have a Control Template similar to this in the **App.xaml**:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="Register" >
  <Grid>
   <TextBox Name="REGUSEBOX"/>
   <ButtonName="REGBUTTON" Click="Button_Click" />
  </Grid
 </ControlTemplate>
```

The **Button_Click** method was generated in the **App.xaml.cs** and it works fine, But I can't access the the Textbox.

How can i access the Textbox in the Click method?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sender` of `Click` event here is a `Button`. you can cast it to `Button` type, take parent (which is `Grid`), find parent's child element by name and cast it to `TextBox`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    Grid grd = button.Parent as Grid;
    TextBox txt = grd.FindName("REGUSEBOX") as TextBox;
}
```

note: wpf approach usually doesn't require such manipulations. Binding for TextBox + Command for Button should allow to do all the job in model, not in code behind. if controls have to change their apperance depending on some conditions, Style and Triggers can help

Comment: Thanks :) 
This did the job. Just learning some advanced WPF. :>

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is the `Button` Object.

```
Button button = sender as Button;
```

the button is what you want. But, I suggest use `MVVM` Pattern in developing  of WPF.

If you want know more.  [Here go](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial)